# Passing Name of Oozie Coordinator as a Workflow Parameter

Tags: java, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

I have an Oozie coordinator in Hue that calls a workflow which has a java action. I would like to pass the name of the coordinator as a parameter to the workflow so that I can pass it to the java action. Is this possible? I see workflow EL functions:
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.5_Hadoop_EL_Functions
But I couldn't find anything for coordinator metadata.

Comment: There are two issues with that link: *(a)* it points to the documentation of a **4 years old** version of Oozie, and *(b)* the link itself is labeled explicitly _**Workflow** documentation_ although it's not really clear from the content >> if you want the Coordinator to pass its name to its child Workflow instance, look into the (current) _Coordinator documentation_ https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no EL function that allows the Coordinator to retrieve its own name dynamically, and pass it to its child Workflow in a custom property.

There are lots of things that you can retrieve about what triggered the execution -- nominal time, execution number, input dataset name etc.-- but not the Coordinator name. What would be the point?

Remember that when you submit the Coordinator, you can just define a **custom parameter** to pass a custom label.
In other words, in addition to the usual `jobTracker` and `nameNode` you can define `coordCustomLabel` or `covfefe` or whatever. And assign that parameter any string value you want -- the Coordinator name, or some free-text comments, or a list of tags.
The custom parameter will be inherited by the Workflow instances -- just like like `jobTracker` and friends.